# Как лучше оформить набор констант в C++?

Tags: c++

Имеется набор констант, представляющих собой смещения в каком-то файле. Эти смещения фиксированы. И имеют разброс от 0 до 0x1FFFFFF. Как бы их максимально удобным способом представить в исходном коде? Код будет с классами. И, соответственно, пространство имен тоже захламлять не хочется.

Варианты на выбор:

1. Макроопределения при помощи `define`. Плохо, что слов нет.
2. `const` в нужном количестве. Возможно внутри какого-то отдельного `namespace` - хорошо, но кажется весьма муторным набирать их в нужном количестве.
3. `enum`. Тут проблема в том, что константы будут идти не подряд. И опять же получается не очень удобно.

Конечно, можно еще сделать структуру с выравниваем =1 и внутрь нее запихать нужное количество переменных и массивов. Но это совсем не ООП получается. И что будет в случае, если формат файла поменяется (добавится хвостик)? Некрасиво короче.

Что я забыл или упустил?

Comment: Может поискать метод вычисления смещений(или хранить их в заголовке самого файла) и вообще избавиться от констант таким образом? Жесткое кодирование смещений с ходу кажется плохой идеей.

Comment: Эм... метода вычисления смещений никакого нет. Вот они есть и точка.

> Жесткое кодирование смещений с ходу кажется плохой идеей

Вопросы к товарищам, которые разработали формат файла. ИМХО. На самом деле он достаточно удобен, ибо в каждой версии имеет фиксированный размер. Но версий несколько. И поддерживать придется каждую. Формат естественно бинарный. Был бы текстовый - было б еще хуже =)

Comment: @gecube, так у Вас предполагается работа одной и той же программы с несколькими форматами?

Тогда, насколько я понимаю, одно и тоже имя "константы" может, в зависимости от формата, давать разные смещения.

В таком случае, не думаю, что вариант @Котик\_хочет\_кушать будет удобен для программирования. Возможно лучшим вариантом окажется массив (размером с количество форматов) структур с **одинаковыми именами** полей.

Заполнение этих полей величинами смещений - это, конечно, отдельная песня, но вот доступ к данным по таким смещениям (понятно, косвенный) получится удобным.

Comment: В лучших традициях ООП на каждый формат будет свой класс loader'а в отдельном файле, так что проблемы нет

Comment: @gecube, очень часто результатом "лучших традиций ООП" является так много слов, что суть программы тонет в них.

Чем проще - тем лучше (но, не проще, чем необходимо).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется разумным вариант с константами в `unnamed` неймспейсе. Попробую аргументировать:

- Значения каких-то там файловых `offset'`ов являются **деталью реализации,** поэтому нет необходимости предоставлять к ним какой-то доступ извне.
- Если по каким-то причинам несколько разных классов должны иметь доступ к этим константам, то можно использовать поименованный неймспейс типа `detail` или же изменить код таким образом, чтобы использование констант было локализовано в одном из них. Второй вариант в этом случае кажется предпочтительнее.
- Такое решение лучше, чем `enum,` поскольку идеологически `enum` служит для поименованного представления некоторого набора **уникальных** значений. Если речь идет про `offset'`ы в файле, то у вас, скорее всего, нет строгой гарантии этой самой уникальности, поэтому использование `enum` может запутать будущего читателя кода.
- Не очень понятна ваша фраза про *"муторность набирания".* Код вида `const unsigned int kInitialFileOffset = 25` субъективно выглядит не слишком сложным для набора `:)`
- Если посмотреть исходный код более-менее известных проектов, то, например, авторы `Chromium` [используют именно такой подход:](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=const+int+k)

  ```
  namespace {

  // If the remaining session time falls below this threshold, the user should be
  // informed that the session is about to expire.
  const int kExpiringSoonThresholdInSeconds = 5 * 60;  // 5 minutes.

  // Color in which the remaining session time is normally shown.
  const SkColor kRemainingTimeColor = SK_ColorWHITE;
  // Color in which the remaining session time is shown when it is expiring soon.
  const SkColor kRemainingTimeExpiringSoonColor = SK_ColorRED;
  ```

Comment: Да, мне нравится. Здоровски. `namespace` у нас чтобы ограничить видимость констант текущим файлом?

> субъективно выглядит не слишком сложным для набора
Ну, в принципе, да, копипастом - да, не очень тяжело.

Comment: Я немного подкорректировал ответ — в прошлой версии одновременное использование `unnamed` `namespace` и `static const` было лишним:

> `[7.3.1.1]` The use of the `static` keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope, the unnamed-namespace provides a superior alternative.

`[7.3.1.1 / Note 82]` Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

Comment: В общем, ответ @Котик_хочет_кушать мне понравился больше всего. Решение действительно опрятное и функциональное.

Answer (score 2):

я за вариант с структурой. Правда не объязательно делать одну большую, а разбить на логические составляющие. Эти структуры могут быть приватными членами класса.

> Но это совсем не ООП получается.

Как Вы думаете, 100500 строк, в которых разобраться сложно, много констант или 2-3 чтения структур. А ещё скорость...
Я думаю, что это нормальный ООП.

> И что будет в случае, если формат файла поменяется (добавится хвостик)?

У Вас файл будет меняться регулярно? плохо. Но если чтение будет разбито на несколько логических структур, то просто либо заменить одну или добавить ещё одну. И всех делов.

Comment: Дело в том, что со структурой такой нюанс выползает, что формат не мой и меня интересуют вполне конкретные области файла. Скажем, немного в начала, немного в конце, немного в середине. Все что между - для меня по сути мусор. Файл достаточно объемен. Скажем, ~10МБ. Поэтому целиком его в структуру засосать будет проблематично. Да и не нужно.

Comment: Главное, что бы потом не выяснилось, что эти значения нужны. Но нужно посмотреть детальнее, может там две-три области, где нужно читать данные - под них и будут локальные структуры.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, константы, определяемые где-либо или разбросанные по неймспейсу( что еще хуже ) - плохой стиль. Вероятно, вы могли наткнуться на [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172091/). Посмотрите пятый пункт, в котором рекомендуется заменять константы функциями, возвращающими некое статическое значение. Функции, конечно же можно логически объединить в класс или структуру и даже сделать их статическими( в логическом пространстве ).
Например, такое определение:

```
MAX_ITERATIONS = 25
```

Может быть заменено на подобное:

```
int getMaxIterations()
{
  return 25;
}
```

Comment: Статью, конечно, читал. Рад, что и Вы ее видели. На мой взгляд, изложенные в ней тезисы весьма спорные. Но на задуматься она бесспорно полезна. 

За попытку ответить спасибо. Функции мне не нравятся. В них не видна семантика константности. Завтра придет дядя Вася и вернет ссылку на нечто. На мой взгляд, константа должна быть константой. Тем более, что в конечном итоге компилятор может ее соптимизировать. С другой стороны, я видел указанный Вами подход в паре проектов, но он там был действительно оправдан. Причем это были функции-члены, которые в классе потомка были переопределены.

Comment: @gecube, функции вместо констант мне тоже не симпатичны. А вот рассуждения о том кто придет завтра...

У Вас сколько человек весь проект делает? А модуль (я имею в виду **НЕ** единицу компиляции) с обработкой форматов файлов?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал enum, который также может быть приватным членом класса.
Расширить enum будет не трудно на мой взгляд, например:

```
enum Offset
{
    Field1 = 0x00000003,
    Field2 = 0x0000000a,
    Reserved = Field2+1
};
```

Такая практика часто встречается, например в библиотеке Qt.